# chr() function in Perl and String.fromCharCode() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, perl, unicode, utf-8

In Perl I am using chr() function. In case my values are lees than 0, I add 256 to the value and use the chr() function. E,g.
For -97 value I add 256, and execute chr(159) and I get Ÿ character.

Now I have to use same in JavaScript.

I am getting -97 and if I add 256 to it and execute String.fromCharCode(159) I get a blank character and instead of that if I execute String.fromCharCode(376) I get  Ÿ character which is same as in Perl.

What and why is there a difference? What should I use in JavaScript?

In JavaScript for positive numbers and the numbers which after adding 256 are less than 256 the output is same in Perl and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The `String.fromCharCode` takes a Unicode code point as its argument. U+178 (decimal 376) is Ÿ.

Perl's `chr` uses the character set that your program runs under.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The PERL code is already there and I have to write a JAVASCRIPT / NODE.JS equivalent. Please see if you can suggest how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Perl runs in cp1252 environment, while the JavaScript in UTF-8. For me, I'm getting Ÿ from

```
perl -e 'print chr 376'
```

See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding for a discussion of encodings and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there a workaround where I can change the character set to CP1252 using meta tag in HTML. If yes what exactly is the character set I should be using?

Comment: @user3710967: I'd try cp1252.